# Python: how to pipe to a background process using subprocess.*?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, ipc

I am trying to have Python execute an external program (which continues to run in the background) and write arbitrary data to the program's STDIN.  The program will read STDIN in non-blocking mode and act upon it.

Here's a toy example (ex.py) of the to-be-executed program:
`

```
import fcntl, os, sys, time

orig_fl = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin, fcntl.F_SETFL, orig_fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

i = 0
while True:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        try:
            i = int(line)
        except:
            pass
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
```

Here's my driver program:

```
import os, random, subprocess, time

command = ['/usr/bin/python3', './ex.py']
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

for i in range(100):
    new_base = 100 * (i + 10)
    print('drive.py setting new_base to', new_base)
    proc.communicate(str(new_base).encode())
    time.sleep(5)
```

I get this:

```
drive.py setting new_base to 1000
1000
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
[...]
```

... whereas I expect something like:

```
drive.py setting new_base to 1000
1000
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
drive.py setting new_base to 1100
1100
1101
[...]
```

So proc.communicate() is blocking or something.

(My "real" executed program is in C and uses fork(), exec(), pipe(), etc., and I *could* do that here I suppose, but it's not the Python way.)

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: `.communicate()` reads from the process's output streams until EOF (which never occurs) or a timeout (which you haven't specified).  So yes, it *is* blocking.  Since you don't seem to care about the process's output, just use `proc.stdin.write()` here.

Comment: @jasonharper that worked with one addition... don't forget to flush()!  Thanks!